# Change date format for variable and get data from other variable

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm a rookie and this is my first post. I'm trying to learn PHP. I have created a plugin in Wordpress, getting data from an external API. The connection is working, however, I would like to change the time format for the variable "application_deadline". Do you have any idea how I can do that? I would also like to get the city/municipality data from the API, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried WorkplaceAddress, city and municipality. You can find the API documentation here: https://jobsearch.api.jobtechdev.se/ (under JobAdSearchResult). Any ideas?

```
 $responseData = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $responseBody );
            $result = json_decode( $responseData );

            $html.= "<div class='all-jobs-wrapper'>";

            foreach($result->hits as $showObj) {
                $html.= "<div class='job-ad-wrapper'>";
                $html.= "<div class='job-ad-title'>" . $showObj->headline . "</div>";
$html.= "<div class='job-ad-city'>" . $showObj->WorkplaceAddress . "</div>";
                $html.= "<div class='job-ad-expires'>" . $showObj->application_deadline . "</div>";
                $html.= "<div class='job-ad-link'> <a class='btn' href='" . $showObj->webpage_url . "'>Sök jobb</a></div>";
                $html.= "</div>";
            }

            $html.= "</div>";
            echo $html;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!